# php simplexml element attributes specific value

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

I am trying to make a primitive form of `meta-search` and i thought that it would require xml parsing.

I have managed to write code for the parser to display the name of all attributes in certain xml tags, but what i am looking for is how to display the elements of a certain attribute's name.

So i want it to only, `&ltdiv id="search"&gt search &lt/div&gt` display the elements with the attribute value of 'search'.

Comment: It would be easier to provide a segment of the XML, what your code is so far and where you are having problems rather than just trying to describe the issue.

Comment: <?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file("google.php") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($xmlobj->items->item as $item) {
    echo "Attribute: " . $item->book->attributes()->category . "n
    echo "Value: " . $item->book . "nn";
}
?> this is the code i am using, what i want it to do is display all tag with a certain attribute value

Comment: i am testing it on the website repl.it and the url for it is: https://repl.it/@venhubtech/MetaSearch-Yahoo-Google-Bing

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59910531/edit) to include all necessary information (including your code since it's unreadable in comments).

Comment: Added code formatting + removed irrelevant references to websites.